# C# async method isn't running modal

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await, mahapps.metro

There is a problem inside my source code that makes a async method not modal.
I am using the Mahapps Metro Framework and I've got a Logger-Class with two async methods in it:

```
public class Logger : ILogger {

    public void outputMessage(string message) {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }

    public void outputUserMessage(string message) {
        MessageBox.Show(message);
    }

    public async void outputMetroUserMessage(object window, String title, String message) {
        MetroWindow mWindow = (MetroWindow)window;
        await mWindow.ShowMessageAsync(title, message);
    }

    public async void outputMetroUserMessageWithHidingMDI(object window, string title, string message) {
        UIGlobals.MainPageMdiChild.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        MetroWindow mWindow = (MetroWindow)window;
        await mWindow.ShowMessageAsync(title, message);
        UIGlobals.MainPageMdiChild.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
}
```

And there are some other classes with methods that call the Logger methods. Example:

```
public partial class Login : MetroWindow {
    public Login() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
        DoLogin();            
    }

    private void DoLogin() {
        String email = txtEMail.Text;
        String password = txtPassword.Password;

        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(email)) {
            Globals.Logger.outputMetroUserMessage(this, UserErrorMessageController.GetTitleByID(103), UserErrorMessageController.GetMessageByID(103));
        } else if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(password)) {
            Globals.Logger.outputMetroUserMessage(this, UserErrorMessageController.GetTitleByID(104), UserErrorMessageController.GetMessageByID(104));
        } else {

            .
            .
            .
        }
    }
 }
```

ProfileCreator:

```
public partial class ProfileCreator : MetroWindow {

    public ProfileCreator(Network tempNetwork, UserProfile tempProfile) {
        InitializeComponent();
        .
        .
        .
    }



    private void btnSave_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
        // TODO: Set cancelling when someting is missing

        Save();
    }

    private void Save() {
        getUserProfileValuesFromWindow();

        Globals.TheSerializer.Serialize(tempProfile, Globals.PathToTemporaryFiles + "MyProfile.xml");

        tempNetwork.NetworkParticipants.Add(tempProfile.ParticipantID);

        Globals.TheSerializer.Serialize(tempNetwork, Globals.PathToTemporaryFiles + "MyNetwork.xml");

        Globals.Logger.outputMetroUserMessage(this, "Erfolg", "Ihr Testsystem wurde erfolgreich angelegt.\nDrücken Sie erneut auf \"Testen\" und loggen Sie sich ein.");
        Globals.Logger.outputMetroUserMessage(this, UserErrorMessageController.GetTitleByID(104), UserErrorMessageController.GetMessageByID(104));
    }
```

When i call the Loggers methods within the Login-Class, the methods run modal as expected, but if i call them from ProfileCreator, they don't seem to be modal. I tried to figure it out, but i cannot see any difference of the classes and parameters. Maybe you will see something i didn't.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You are most likely getting an error you are not seeing when you pass in \nDrücken. Try escaping the whole string with @"Ihr Testsystem wurde erfolgreich...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are not using `Task`.  Best practice is to return `Task` from all `async` methods that are not invoked from a user click event in WPF for example.  Your code should look like this:

```
public class Logger : ILogger
{
    public void outputMessage(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }

    public void outputUserMessage(string message)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(message);
    }

    public Task<MessageDialogResult> outputMetroUserMessage(object window, String title, String message)
    {
        MetroWindow mWindow = (MetroWindow)window;
        return mWindow.ShowMessageAsync(title, message);
    }

    public async Task outputMetroUserMessageWithHidingMDI(object window, string title, string message)
    {
        UIGlobals.MainPageMdiChild.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        MetroWindow mWindow = (MetroWindow)window;
        await mWindow.ShowMessageAsync(title, message);
        UIGlobals.MainPageMdiChild.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
}
```

And consume it as such:

```
public partial class Login : MetroWindow
{
    public Login()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void button_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        await DoLogin();
    }

    private async Task DoLogin()
    {
        String email = txtEMail.Text;
        String password = txtPassword.Password;

        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(email))
        {
            await Globals.Logger.outputMetroUserMessage(this, UserErrorMessageController.GetTitleByID(103), UserErrorMessageController.GetMessageByID(103));
        }
        else if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(password))
        {
            await Globals.Logger.outputMetroUserMessage(this, UserErrorMessageController.GetTitleByID(104), UserErrorMessageController.GetMessageByID(104));
        }
        else
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I am only using `async void` on the event handler from the UI, this should be the only place you use that pattern.  Please read through [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) for explanations.

Here is the final piece, again do not use async void unless you are the method that is the event handler from a UI interaction.

```
public partial class ProfileCreator : MetroWindow
{
    public ProfileCreator(Network tempNetwork, UserProfile tempProfile)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // ...
    }

    async void btnSave_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: Set cancelling when someting is missing
        await Save();
    }

    async Task Save()
    {
        getUserProfileValuesFromWindow();

        Globals.TheSerializer.Serialize(tempProfile, Globals.PathToTemporaryFiles + "MyProfile.xml");

        tempNetwork.NetworkParticipants.Add(tempProfile.ParticipantID);

        Globals.TheSerializer.Serialize(tempNetwork, Globals.PathToTemporaryFiles + "MyNetwork.xml");

        await Globals.Logger.outputMetroUserMessage(this, "Erfolg", "Ihr Testsystem wurde erfolgreich angelegt.\nDrücken Sie erneut auf \"Testen\" und loggen Sie sich ein.");
        await Globals.Logger.outputMetroUserMessage(this, UserErrorMessageController.GetTitleByID(104), UserErrorMessageController.GetMessageByID(104));
    }
}
```

Comment: But this doesn't explain, why the method is modal when called from Login, and not modal when called by ProfileCreator.

Comment: Perhaps that has something to do with your `UIGlobals`, which is a really big concern in my opinion.  But with the way it was before, it could yield unexpected results -- async void is essentially fire-and-forget.  What that means is that you do not know what is going to happen.

Comment: Nevertheless your code works perfectly. Thanks alot :)

Comment: I'm happy I could help!  Thank you for the acceptance of the answer.

Comment: You just took away from my answer, now it is unaccepted?  You can only accept one correct answer...

Comment: Oh sorry, i thought i can accept multiple answers. you were the first one who answere correctly my Thread, so you get the Accept ;)

Answer (score 1):

That's because you call your async Method "outputMetroUserMessage" twice, without waiting for the result of the first one. you can redefine your method like this:

```
public Task<MessageDialogResult> OutputMetroUserMessage(object window, string title, string message)
{
   MetroWindow mWindow = (MetroWindow)window;
   return mWindow.ShowMessageAsync(title, message);
}
```

and than await the message outputs:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            await this.OutputMetroUserMessage(this, "Title", "Message1");
            await this.OutputMetroUserMessage(this, "Title", "Message2");
        }
```

the second call will be executed after the message acknowlegded by the user.

hope that helps.